# how to add a reference with two parts in Bibliography in Latex?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

For normal case I was using

```
@article{abc,
    Author={Author}, 
    Journal={J. Physics},
    Number={1}, 
    Pages={1},
    Year={1900}
}
```

The result is

> Author. J. Physics.  (1):1,1900.

I am using `natbib`  and adding bibliography in the `.bib` file.
Now I want

> (a) Author. J. Physics.  (1):1,1900.; (b) patent no. 123

which means I want to include patent number such that the reference contains two parts as

(a) the author and Journal details (b) patent number.

Comment: Hi and welcome, can you please elaborate a bit on that? The question as it is now is a bit unclear to me.

Comment: Are you having trouble defining the right fields *or* getting the right output? It is important for us to know in which way you are including your bibliography ... the old system with bibtex and maybe `natbib` or any other system; or `biblatex` in conjunction with `biber`? Please provide a [minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html) to show us all we need to give some useful hints.

Comment: I try to re-modify my question to make it more clear.

Comment: If i understood that correctly, this is not a matter of different parts, but two completely individual bib-entries.

Comment: I want this form because with this reference always patent number is added by splitting the single reference into (a) and (b) part.